# Throw and handle custom exception during authentication Spring Security + WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm trying to throw a custom exception in WebFlux during authentication, and handle it with a ControllerAdvice (`@ExceptionHandler`). Unfortunately, it doesn't get propagated, I'm getting either HTTP 500 if I throw the exception, or HTTP 401 if I return the exception as Mono.error()

```
@Override //in authentication service
public Mono<UserDetails> findByUsername(String username) {
    //find user by username from database, 
    //if not enabled, throw a custom exception, 
    //if doesn't exist, throw UsernameNotFoundException, 
    //return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User otherwise.
}

@ExceptionHandler //in controller advice
public Mono<HttpStatus> handleException(MyCustomExceptionThrownFromFindByUsername ex) {
    //implemented
}
```

Is there any way to help the exception to make it to the ExceptionHandler?

Comment: Why? The check for using an enabled user is already done by Spring Security for you so why do it here in a place that isn't responsible for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum actually it does not, or I'm doing something wrong, org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User only cares about username, password and authorities.

Comment: No it doesn't... It implements `UserDetails` which has `isEnabled`... There is a constructor that takes a 4 additional booleans to indicate different user states. Default for all of them is `true`. Use the proper constructor and let Spring Security handle the rest.Also regardless of the error Spring Security will issue 401. You don't want to provide more details from a security perspective... (If a hacker does a brute force and gets more information like *account is disabled* he knows that it is an existing account).

Comment: @M.Deinum even if I'm using a wrong UserDetails implementation for this, I'm curious how my exception disappears, I'm still learning the framework.

Comment: @M.Deinum I overlooked the other constructor somehow. :) If you add this as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You aren't using the wrong implementation you are doing things in the wrong place, next to that you should indeed use `Mono.error` and that will always lead to a 401.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UserDetailsService` (both [reactive](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/ReactiveUserDetailsService.html) and [non-reactive](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html)) has as a job to retrieve the user based on the `username`. Nothing more and nothing less. Checking if the user is enabled is delegated to a [`UserDetailsChecker`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsChecker.html) which calls some methods on the `UserDetails` implementation and will react accordingly. Don't try to do more in here as that isn't the task of the `UserDetailsService`.

The default `UserDetails`, [`User`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) implementation has 2 constructors, one with 3 and one with 7 parameters. Use the second one to fill the `enabled` properly according to your business rules and Spring Security will do the rest as it should.